# How to write $(f^{-1})'(b)=\frac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}(b)\right)}$ in Leibnizian notation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

On Calculus by Spivak question 12-17 we are asked to rewrite this equation in  Leibnizian notation

> $$(f^{-1})'(b)=\frac{1}{f'\big(f^{-1}(b)\big)}\text{.}$$

The answer book says that it should be written

> $$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\dfrac{dy}{dx}} . \tag{1}$$

But, wouldn't this be the translation for

$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(x)} ? \tag{2}$$

How is (1) the correct translation? If (1) is the correct translation, how would one write (2) in Leibnizian notation?

Comment: On the right hand side, $dy/dx$ does not make clear at which point it is evaluated. Why do you evaluate it at $x$ instead of at $f^{-1}(b)$?

Comment: It should be added that next to the answer on the answer book there is a parenthesis that states "(In this formula, it is understood that $dx/dy$ means $(f^{-1})'(y)$, while $dy/dx$ is an "expression involving $x$," and in the final answer $x$ must be replaced by $y$, by means of the queation $y=f(x)$.)".

Comment: Im so sorry, typo, it should be $x$ on the LHS and the RHS (I have edited out the error).

Comment: [Avoid](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles) `\displaystyle` in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$y(x) = f(x) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Using $b$ as a replacement for $y$ results in

$$x(y) = f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(b) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Substituting \eqref{eq2A} into \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$y(x) = y(f^{-1}(y)) = y(f^{-1}(b)) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Remember the "$'$" symbol used with a function means to differentiate that function wrt its argument. Thus, you get from \eqref{eq2A}

$$(f^{-1})'(b) = (f^{-1})'(y) = x'(y) = \frac{dx}{dy} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

plus from \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq3A} you get

$$f'(f^{-1}(b)) = f'(x) = y'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This means you have

$$(f^{-1})'(b)=\frac{1}{f'\big(f^{-1}(b)\big)} \implies \dfrac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\dfrac{dy}{dx}} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Regarding your statement of

$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(x)} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

note you're using the same argument, i.e., $x$ for both a function *and* its inverse in the same expression. This doesn't really work. Nonetheless, if you did try this to implement this in Leibnizian notation, it might be something like

$$\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{1}{\dfrac{dy}{dx}} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Comment: Sorry if this question is too silly but, why did you sometimes use "$y(x)$" and sometimes just "$y$" (the same goes for "$x$" and "$x(y)$")? I was able to follow everythin else, it was very clear, thanks.

Comment: @RandomUser You're welcome for the help. Note I used $y(x)$ when I wanted to emphasize that $y$ is a function of $x$. However, I didn't use it everywhere to avoid having too many extra brackets & variables involved which I was concerned would make the expressions more difficult to read and, perhaps, detract from the point I was trying to make. If you wish, e.g., if it helps you to see & understand what's going on, you can certainly replace all instances where I just used $y$ with $y(x)$ instead.